# Evaluate the Integral when given f and f'.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Suppose that $f''$ is continuous on $[1, 3]$ and $f(1) = 8, f(3) = −8, f'(1) = 8$ and $f'(3) = 3$. Evaluate $$\int_1^3 x f''(x)\ \mathrm dx$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Let $u = x$ and $dv = f''(x) dx$ then use integration by parts

$$\int_1^3 xf''(x) dx = xf'(x)|_1^3 - \int_1^3f'(x) dx $$

Comment: I am having a hard time figuring out what f"(x) is, i know how to do the integral i just don't know how to find f"x

Comment: You don't need $f ''$. You just need to evaluate $x f' (x)$ on $3$ and $1$ and $\int_1^3 f'(x) dx = f(3) - f(1)$.

Comment: So I need to know what F'(x) is? I still don't know how to find that...

Comment: On this case, $F(x) = f(x)$. Notice that $F'(x) = f'(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

By integration by parts,

$$\int_1^3 xf''(x)\, dx = xf'(x)\bigg|_{x = 1}^3 - \int_1^3 f'(x)\, dx = 3f'(3) - f'(1) - (f(3) - f(1))$$

Now substitute the values for $f(1), f(3), f'(1)$, and $f'(3)$.